# How to render and stop from an internal method

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

Suppose I have this action structure:

```
def checkAccess(request: Request[AnyContent]) {
    if (shouldntGetAccess()) {
        // I want to return 404 and stop execution here
    }
}

def index = Action { implicit request =>
    checkAccess(request)

    Ok
}
```

How do I decide to return a 404 page from `checkAccess()` and stop execution? This was achieved in Play 1 with simply calling `notFound()`, but doesn't seem to behave the same in Play 2.

Could this be achieved by having `checkAccess()` throw some exception, and adding a filter to capture it and render the correct response? If you code provide a code sample, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def checkAccess(f: Request[AnyContent] => Result) = Action{ request => 
  if(shouldntGetAccess()){
  NotFound
}else{
  f(request)
}
}

def index = checkAccess{ request => 
  Ok("success")
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting functional approach.